# adding buttons with infro from intent in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

Suppose I have 2 activity pages activity1 and activity2. Now activity1 passes an intent to activity2. This intent contains info on how many buttons need to be created in activity2. 
In other words there will be some number of buttons in activity2 page, which is dependent on the info from the intent.

How do I do this in my activity2 java file? I have a scroll view layout already setup in activity2, so please also explain how to add the buttons sequentially on that layout.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Show some code? Otherwise I'd direct you to http://developer.android.com/training.

Comment: Its not about `adding buttons with infro from intent ` but u need to create dynamically buttons in your second Activity. so search about it. there are lots of examples & Answers for adding dynamically buttons in your view & passing the different kind of datas within intent.First Search then Ask.

Comment: If its no of buttons pass that integer in intent from 1st activity to 2nd..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approximately, something like that :

```
    int numberOfButtons = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("numberOfButtons", 0);
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfButtons; ++i)
    {
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("Button n° " + i);

        // YOUR_WIDGET_THAT_WILL_CONTAIN_YOUr_BUTTONS.addView(btn);

    }
```